# Expression-combination of "A or B or both"

Tags: python, pyparsing

Here is what I currently have:

```
_filter_date_range = pp.Group(_keyword_date + pp.Group(
    pp.Group(_function_before + _argument_string) & pp.Group(_function_after + _argument_string)
))
```

Since I use `Each`(`&`), both expressions are required. But I want to allow:

- A or B
- or both
- but at least one
- in whatever order

If I make both groups `Optional`, I would also allow neither, which I don't want. So is there something I can use for that?

Comment: I guess I'm not following the question, but why wouldn't a or (`|`) be sufficient?

Comment: Because OP wants to allow "or both". So `OneOrMore(A|B)` might work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are three possible solutions for you:

```
from pyparsing import Literal, OneOrMore, Optional

A = Literal("A")
B = Literal("B")

language = OneOrMore( A | B )

assert language.matches("A")
assert language.matches("B")
assert language.matches("A B")
assert language.matches("B A")
assert language.matches("A A")
assert language.matches("B B")
assert language.matches("A B A B")
assert not language.matches("")

def EitherOrBoth(a, b):
    return (a + b) | (b + a) | a | b
language = EitherOrBoth(A, B)

assert language.matches("A")
assert language.matches("B")
assert language.matches("A B")
assert language.matches("B A")
assert not language.matches("A A")
assert not language.matches("B B")
assert not language.matches("A B A B")
assert not language.matches("")

def EitherOrBoth(a, b):
    return (a + Optional(b)) | (b + Optional(a))
language = EitherOrBoth(A, B)

assert language.matches("A")
assert language.matches("B")
assert language.matches("A B")
assert language.matches("B A")
assert not language.matches("A A")
assert not language.matches("B B")
assert not language.matches("A B A B")
assert not language.matches("")
```

Comment: The first option does not really meet the OPs constraints (accepts multiple matches of A or B). My preference is the 3rd option.

Comment: #3 is actually very nice and much closer to defining regular languages that I remember from CS class. Great!

Comment: Also, +1 for using the new `matches()` method!

Answer (score 3):

@Rob's third option of `EitherOrBoth` works very well in this case, I think, but pyparsing's `Each` really comes into its own when you have to deal with 3 or more expressions that can occur in any order:

```
from pyparsing import Literal, Each

A = Literal("A")
B = Literal("B")
C = Literal("C")

def noMoreThanOneOfEachAndAtLeastOne(exprs):
    ret = Each(map(Optional, exprs))
    ret.addCondition(bool)
    return ret
language = noMoreThanOneOfEachAndAtLeastOne([A,B,C])

assert language.matches("A")
assert language.matches("B")
assert language.matches("A C B")
assert language.matches("C A")
assert not language.matches("A A")
assert not language.matches("B B")
assert not language.matches("A B A B")
assert not language.matches("")
```

`addCondition` is a fairly recent addition to pyparsing, a variant on `addParseAction`.  `addCondition` accepts a callable (with the same call signature support as `addParseAction`) which must return a boolean value. If it returns False, then the condition will cause a ParseException to be raised. (This is a simplification of the use case of using a parse action as a validator.) In this case, all we need is the Python builtin `bool`, since ParseResults, like all Python native sequences, evaluate to False when empty and True otherwise.

Comment: So if I understand it correctly, you're using `Each` to combine all possible expressions in any order and `Optional` to make every single expression optional. Then, `addConditional(bool)` will evaluate to `True` if the Result is not empty, enforcing the "at least one"-part. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is how this works. But this is for the more general case of 'n' expressions, where `Each` handles all the order combinations. In the case of your original question, where you are parsing a date-range expression that can have a before-this-time and/or an after-this-time part, @Rob's answer is simpler.

Comment: I ended up using @Rob's solution. Thanks for your input, too!

Comment: This is the solution that I was looking for, but I didn't notice `Each()` in the API doc. I recommend this over mine.